# How to tell KDE to store command line options on session save?

Tags: emacs, kde, session

I use Emacs in daemon mode under KDE, that is, I have `emacs --daemon` running. Everything works fine. If I tell KDE to save session on logout, and restore that saved session on next login, it forgets about the `--deamon` command line option, and brings up a standalone Emacs instance. Is there a way to restore the command line option, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, there is a way to tell KDE not to save certain applications. You should add emacs to KDE's "don't save" list, and then add "emacs --daemon" to your startup programs.

Otherwise, you could always add something like this to your startup programs:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacsclient -e '(kill-emacs)' # try a graceful kill first
pkill emacs
rm -f /tmp/emacs`id -u`/server
emacs --daemon
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I came out with a similar solution, but I thought there is a standard way without the need of a separate shell script.